# How can I upgrade the version of TLS on an application running in app engine to > 1.2

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-cloud-platform, tls1.2

I am running an Angular app inside app engine. Recently this application was PEN tested and one of the issues that came up was around TLS1.0 and TLS 1.1 in use.

The recommendation from these results are to disable all TLS protocols before TLS1.2. Only use cipher suites considered cryptographically strong.

The application presently doesnt have a custom domain and is purely hosted on .appspot.com

How do I achieve this? Would I need to use a custom domain for this? I've tried read around but feel a little out of my comfort zone with this.

Thanks

Comment: We're having the same issue, thought only an ssl policy in the load balancer would fix it. Did they manage to update it for app engine standard? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that you should contact directly [GCP's Support Team](https://cloud.google.com/support/).

Bear in mind that this is not supported within the free trial support package.

If you don't have a Support Plan, upgrading to the [Development](https://cloud.google.com/support/#support-plans) plan with only 1 user would be enough to open a support case and request TLS changes for the needed domains.

Comment: Thank you, I will open up a support ticket with them

Comment: I paid for one month of support to get this done, and Google did it fairly quickly.

Comment: @gaefan We're having the same issue, thought only an ssl policy in the load balancer would fix it. Did they manage to update it for app engine standard? Cheers

Comment: @iSupport, yes, fixed on gae standard.